aws-amplify session and cookies
I have two different projects. Project A (amplify 6) the user can sign in with amplify and if it's successful he will be redirect to Project B (amplify 5), the signIn is working as expected and I know that there's some cookies being saved based on the user information by default from amplify. Moving on to Project B the user can signOut there and here's my problem, I tried both Auth.signOut() and Auth currentAuthenticatedUser() on Project B and it does nothing. currentAuthenticatedUser() returns that there's no authenticated user.
It's my first time working with Amplify and I know that I'm probably missing something here but I thought that with the cookies I could signOut the user on Project B that was authenticated on Project A.
Everything is configured just fine on Project B and I even tried to signUp an user with Amplify just to see if the problem was a configuration that I missed but it worked.
OBS: I'm using amplify 5 on Project B because I had a lot of problems trying to install amplify 6 because of the version of react that I'm using.
What am I missing at Project B to get the authenticated user from Project A?
This is how I'm setting up the cookies on Project A
  const authConfig: ResourcesConfig['Auth'] = {
    Cognito: {
      userPoolId: awsmobile.aws_user_pools_id,
      userPoolClientId: awsmobile.aws_user_pools_web_client_id
    }
  };

  Amplify.configure({Auth: authConfig});

  cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.setKeyValueStorage(new CookieStorage());

On Project B I'm only using signOut() function from Amplify.

You need to pass the domain to the provider:
  cognitoUserPoolsTokenProvider.setKeyValueStorage(new CookieStorage({ domain: <your domain> }))

and sign out with with the param global: true
    await signOut({
      global: true
    })

